# DrRacket REPL not Discarding EOF

Tags: racket

I'm attempting to use `DrRacket`'s REPL to test whether the user has entered a `y` character.

To that end, I'm using code like this:

```
(eq? (read-char) #\y)
```

When I run this code, `DrRacket` displays an input textbox with an **EOF** button which I imagine I'm supposed to click when I'm done with my input.

So my input, then is <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>eof</kbd> which returns true, but then when I run the line of code a second time, I don't get the textbox; instead, it immediately returns false. I'm guessing this is because it hasn't discarded the <kbd>eof</kbd> from the buffer, and so it's comparing this with `y`.

How can I tell the REPL not to include the <kbd>eof</kbd> in the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are meant to click the EOF-button when you want to send an eof-object.
In principle when the end-of-file-object is read, no more input should appear on the port.

In the repl the user normally uses enter/return to signal that the input is done.
I therefore recommend you also use this convention in DrRacket.

This program:

```
#lang racket    
(define (yes? [display-message #t])
  (when display-message
    (displayln "Enter y or n:"))
  (match (read-line)
    ["y" 'yes]
    ["n" 'no]
    [else (yes? #f)]))

(displayln (yes?)) (flush-output)
(displayln (yes?)) (flush-output)
```

seems to work (also when the eof-button is used).

Comment: Instead of "y" as the match pattern, you can use a regular expression that matches both "y" and "yes".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying re the EOF button; however, I get the same behavior when using Enter: the newline character is saved in the buffer and consumed by the next call to `read-char`.

Comment: In the solution above I use `read-line` to read both the character and the newline. If you want to use `read-char` then you need to read both the the character and the following newline (i.e. use two calls to `read-char` instead of one). For better advice post the actual code.

Comment: I got stuck when using the `user-says-yes` method in this assignment: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps2tw1/readme.html. I'll just use yours instead.